# How to set a cookie age without using a framework in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cookies

I cannot find any information on setting the age of a cookie without using an external module. I know how to set the cookie but not its age and want to do it without the use of a library.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response.writeHead(200, {
'Set-Cookie':'sesh=wakadoo; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+86409000).toUTCString()
});
```

This will set the expiry date of `1 day` for the cookie

Comment: One day and 9 seconds, to be precise.

Comment: Where's the documentation for this because node only provide info for setting the cookie and no more to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
//....
response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['type=ninja', 'language=javascript']);
//....
```

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Comment: There's nothing about setting a cookie expiration in this answer which is what the OP is asking about.