# Node.js: How to set multiple cookies

Tags: node.js

I've modified the code I got from this thread: [How to set a cookie age without using a framework in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420630/how-to-set-a-cookie-age-without-using-a-framework-in-node-js)

But it only works for the last variable. How can I have both of them working? Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie':'test1=' + result[1] + '; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+30 * 60000).toUTCString(),
    'Set-Cookie':'test2=' + result[2] + '; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+30 * 60000).toUTCString() // 30 minutes
});
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

> Use an array of strings here to send multiple headers with the same name.

So just do what you're doing but use an array:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie':['test1=' + result[1] + '; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+30 * 60000).toUTCString(),
                  'test2=' + result[2] + '; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+30 * 60000).toUTCString()] // 30 minutes
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work it creates just single cookie this way: test1=mmmmmm; Path=/api/auth; Domain=localhost; Expires=Wed, 04 Nov 2020 18:07:32 GMT;
My code:
res.writeHead(200, {
      'Set-Cookie': ['test1=mmmmmm; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 
        60000).toUTCString(),
      'test2=nnnnn; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 60000).toUTCString() ]// 30 minutes
    });

Comment: @TaherGhulamMohammed see my answer below. Hopefully helpfull for you, i had the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation (in my case NodeJS v14):

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/all.html#http_request_getrawheadernames

I've tried this:

```
const cookieTime = 1234567891; //Default Timestamp without ms
const cookieValue1 = "TestVal"; //Cookie Value 1
const cookieValue2 = "AnotherVal"; //Cookie Value 1
const maxAge = 60*60*24; //24h in seconds

const cookieOptions = ";expires="+cookieTime+";domain=.domain.tld;visited=true; Max-Age="+maxAge+"; HttpOnly; Secure";

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['cookie1='+cookieValue1+cookieOptions, 'cookie2='+cookieValue2+cookieOptions]);
```

This works perfectly fine without any additional modules, despite the obvious ones "http" or "https" for response/request handling in a callback.

> Q: Why using res.setHeader() instead of res.writeHead()?
>
> A: In my case, i need to send more data afterwards.

Since my code is ugly here is a snippet of pseudocode:

```
response = http(s) response from callback

String: Action = 'Set-Cookie'

Array: Cookies = [
     String: 'cookieName=cookieValue;cookieOption=cookieOptionValue;....;',
     String: 'cookieName=cookieValue;cookieOption=cookieOptionValue;....;',
     ....,
     ....
]

response.setHeader(
     String: Action,
     Array: Cookies
)
```

If you need further information on available actions or cookie options:

-) [available response actions](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

-) [available cookie options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#syntax)

Could be also usefull for this thread: [How to set a cookie age without using a framework in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420630/how-to-set-a-cookie-age-without-using-a-framework-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use express and cookie parser for this job. It is pretty simple to set a cookie:

```
res.cookie('cookiename', 'value',options)
```

And to get a cookie:

```
req.cookies["cookiename"]
```

Answer (score -2):

In your example, you are just overwriting the 'Set-Cookie' property in the object.

Multiple key value pairs delimited by semi-colons is the way to go.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie':'test1=' + result[1] + ';test2=' + result[2] + '; expires='+new Date(new Date().getTime()+30 * 60000).toUTCString(),
});
```