# Running res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie) twice in two functions at login

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I have the following function which runs at login of my application in Next JS

```
import { Magic } from "@magic-sdk/admin";
import { createSession, createSessionId } from "../../utils/auth-cookie.js";
import { authClient } from "../../utils/faunaAuth.js";
import { q, adminClient } from "../../utils/faunadb.js";

// Initiating Magic instance for server-side methods
const magic = new Magic(process.env.MAGIC_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function login(req, res) {
  try {
    const didToken = req.headers.authorization.substr(7);
    await magic.token.validate(didToken);

    async function createUser(email) {
      return adminClient.query(
        q.Create(q.Collection("User"), {
          data: { email },
        })
      );
    }

    let user;

    async function getUserByEmail(email) {
      return adminClient
        .query(q.Get(q.Match(q.Index("unique_User_email"), email)))
        .catch(() => undefined);
    }

    async function obtainFaunaDBToken(user) {
      return adminClient
        .query(q.Create(q.Tokens(), { instance: q.Select("ref", user) }))
        .then((res) => res?.secret)
        .catch(() => undefined);
    }

    if (await getUserByEmail(req.body.email)) {
      user = await getUserByEmail(req.body.email);
    } else {
      user = await createUser(req.body.email);
    }

    const token = await obtainFaunaDBToken(user);

    const { ref, data } = await authClient(token).query(
      q.Get(q.CurrentIdentity())
    );

    // ISSUE HAPPENS HERE

    await createSession(res, { token });
    await createSessionId(res, { id: ref.id });

    res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, user });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```

CreateSession utility functions

```
import { serialize, parse } from "cookie";


const TOKEN_NAME = "fauna_client";
const ID = "ID";
const MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 8; // 8 hours

export async function createSession(res, data) {

  // THIS IS CONSOLING JUST FINE
  // BUT WONT WRITE COOKIE
  // BUT CREATESESSIONID WILL WRITE COOKIE

  console.log("should be token", data.token);

  const cookie = serialize(TOKEN_NAME, data.token, {
    //maxAge: MAX_AGE,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + MAX_AGE * 1000),
    // httpOnly: true,
    // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "lax",
  });

  console.log("res", res);

  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);
}

export async function createSessionId(res, data) {

  console.log("should be id", data.id);

  const cookie = serialize(ID, data.id, {
    //maxAge: MAX_AGE,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + MAX_AGE * 1000),
    // httpOnly: true,
    // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "lax",
  });

  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);
}
```

For whatever reason the ID cookie get's set but the fauna_client cookie the token never get's set, I swear this worked the first time, but I have a feeling that maybe you can only set the cookie once on the header before it timesout or something. Not exactly sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe this can help you `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [ array of cookies ])` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977044/node-js-how-to-set-multiple-cookies

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial that worked, not sure what we should do about the answer here but this worked `res.setHeader("Set-Cookie",[cookie, cookie1] );` if ya wanna use it for the answer

Comment: You may close this question if you wish, for this question itself is a duplicate.